# in MySQL, MAX() command returns an incorrect result

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database which have columns with
id, adsoyad, tag_id, map_id, xpos, ypos, and date.

This database receives data from each user every 15 minutes. Each user has a unique tag_id. The structure of the "date" column is in datetime format.
When I run the code below;

```
SELECT tag_id, xpos, ypos, adsoyad, date, MAX(date) 
FROM `lt_position` 
WHERE map_id="750" 
GROUP BY tag_id
```

A column named Max(date) appears, the groupings are correct, but the Max(date) column lists the previous entry, not the last entry.

when I run this code, while listing, it lists the last registration date and the previous registration of the person.

What I want is to see the xpos and ypos data that each user submitted at the last registration time.

I tried some different code which I found in different solutions on the web and also from stackoverflow. But all of them give the same results to me.

I guessed my database has some problem. I tried to repair it a few times. I deleted and created it once. But the result is still the same.

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: See also [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: What are the results of the query?

Comment: As well as removing the pictures, you need to replace it with text-based sample data, and text-based expected results. Having no data at all in the question makes it impossible to answer accurately. Read the guidance I provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to see the xpos and ypos data that each user submitted at the last registration time.

If so, that's a typical top-1-per-group problem.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can solve it with window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select p.*,
        rank() over(partition by tag_id order by date desc) rn
    from lt_position p
    where map_id = 750
) p
where rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, where window functions are not available, one alternative uses a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from lt_position p
where map_id = 750
  and l.date = (select max(p1.date) from lt_position p1 where p1.tag_id = t.tag_id)
```

For performance with the second query, consider an index on `lt_position(tag_id, date)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not include images in the question. Use text instead.

You should tell from what set you want the `max` from (max of what?). You seem to have both `date` and `max(date)` in the query.

`GROUP BY` statement should include all non-aggregate columns from the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Please execute below query to see whether the tag_id wise max date is in the top or not.

```
SELECT tag_id, xpos, ypos, adsoyad, date FROM `lt_position` WHERE map_id="750" order BY tag_id date
```

Please also execute this:

```
SELECT tag_id, MAX(date) 
FROM `lt_position` 
WHERE map_id="750" 
GROUP BY tag_id
```

Comment: thank you.. But, I have 5 different user and there is about 1000 entry. I want to see on a new table only last entries of those 5 persons.

Comment: I got that. But I just wanted to know that the desired data is available in the list or not.